# Retaining Model data when passed between views

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have 2 views both with forms.

I use TempData to pass between views. Which works fine. View2 receives data from View1 through common Model object. The model's data comes from both View1 & View2.

But when View2's form is submitted, the model does not retain View1's data. They are all reset to null & 0.

This is understandable looking at how HTTP works.

But what is the best way to get data from multiple views in a single Model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possibilities to consider:

- Use the Session to store the values from View1 in between form POSTs.
- Place the View1 data in hidden fields on View2.  That way it will be retained when View2's form is POSTed.